# Twig: how to localize time_diff filter

Tags: symfony, twig, intl

How to translate `time_diff` Twig filter?

I've setup all the needed to localize templates. In fact, if I use `localizeddate` the date is formatted following the `locale`variable I've set.

But, how to translate `time_diff`?

This is the code I'm using:

```
<time title="{{ order.srcCompletedOn|localizeddate('long', 'none', locale) }}" datetime="{{ order.srcCompletedOn|localizeddate('long', 'none', locale) }}">{{ order.srcCompletedOn|time_diff }}</time>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig date time\_diff translation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34568838/twig-date-time-diff-translation)